# Array child in conditional rendering in vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel, vue.js

I have api on laravel and front on vue + laravel. I am getting all the data from api and pass it to view. Now I want to do conditional rendering.

My array looks like:

```
 "data" => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:5 [▶]
    1 => array:5 [▶]
```

I want to show div if topic from link is the same topic from array. But I do not know how to search and compare that words.
So it will be like that:

```
v-if="$topic == this.topic"
```

But now I can only use

```
v-if="$data[]['0']['topic']"
```

and then I have the same topic on all my views.

My link looks like:

```
/user/{topic}/post
```

How to do it correctly guys?

Answer (score 0):

I did it using foreach, the easiest way :)